# speech is to speaking as [X] is to writing and [Y] is to reading

Tags: word-choice, analogy

I'm writing a CV and would like to describe my English language skills... how well I can read, write and speak English. Well, it seems I'm lacking a couple of nouns...

If speech is to speaking as **X** is to writing and **Y** is to reading, what could **X** and **Y** be?

Answer (score 2):

The words are "reading", "writing", and "speaking".

You can describe your abilities, or self-assess them, as follows:

- reading comprehension - quite good
- writing - poor
- listening comprehension - poor
- speaking (or oral production) - good

I wouldn't use "speech"

Comment: *I wouldn't use "speech".* Then you need to write your own question. ;-) This question is not about how *speaking* relates to *speaking*.  It is about how *speech* relates to *speaking*.

Comment: OP says he was lacking a couple of nouns. Centaurus supplied them. The fact that "speech" can be synonymous with "speaking" means we don't have to substitute anything else for "reading" or "writing" to satisfy the "as X is to " test, because they are nouns synonymous respectively with themselves.

Comment: @Drew  The question is about what to write in a CV,  concerning one's "English Language skills" as the OP says it.   That's how I understand it  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my view and experience your question should be: If speech is to speaking THEN X is to writing and Y is to reading. What is X and Y?

The answer then is: Write and read.

Comment: Surely not. *Speech* is a noun. *Write* and *read* are verbs.

Comment: James, welcome to stackexchange.net . Unfortunately, like @Drew suggests, your answer can't be the one. Consider removing it (otherwise people might downvote it, and having some reputation is useful on this site...)